# How to Create the .apk of web application of React.js

Tags: apk, reactjs

I am working with React.js web  Application And I am Fresher with React.js.

Actually my requirement is I want to make a mobile app using the React.js.

I am talking about the .apk. can we develop web app as well as mobile app using

React.js. please share if we can or not and give other ideas how to achieve web

app and  mobile app using React.js.

Comment: You can use ionic and native script for this purpose

Comment: Mean ionic will be used for the both web app and mobile app

Comment: [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) is designed for creating native mobile apps with React.

Comment: Yes... you can! Using Phonegap

Comment: Or also Cordova https://cordova.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can not generate APK files from React.JS
You can do it with **React-Native**

Answer (score 0):

Search about Progressive Web Application With React configuration